# Como mostrar una alerta faltando 10 minutos de una hora especifica

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, popup

actualmente tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
let start_date = '';
        var now = new Date();
        let validation_date = '';
        const $topleft = $(this.refs.topleft);

        const message_popup = result.map(item => {
            if (moment(item.start).format(Config.DateFormat) == moment(now).format(Config.DateFormat))
            {
                start_date = moment(item.start).format(Config.DateTimeFormat);
                validation_date = new Date(moment(start_date).get('year'), moment(start_date).get('month'), moment(start_date).get('date'), moment(start_date).get('hour'), moment(start_date).get('minute'), moment(start_date).get('second'), moment(start_date).get('millisecond')) - now;
                if (validation_date < 0) {
                    //validation_date += 86400000;
                    validation_date += 72000000;
                }
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        message: `${ILocale.MsgAlertaEventoP1} ${item.title}${ILocale.MsgAlertaEventoP2} ${moment(item.start).format(Config.TimeFormatAmPm)}`,
                        className: 'bb-alternate-modal'
                    });
                }, validation_date);
            }
        });
```

Lo que quisera hacer es, desplegar una alerta 10 minutos antes de la hora solicitada de la BD, alguna idea de como hacerlo...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lo que quisera hacer es, desplegar una alerta 10 minutos antes de la hora solicitada de la BD. ¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Lo que tendrías que hacer es primero restarle 10 minutos a la fecha obtenida. Finalmente obtienes la diferencia en milisegundos entre esta fecha y la fecha de *ahora*.

**Ejemplo**

```js
// simula una fecha 1 minuto adelante
const datedb = moment().add(1, 'minutes');
// le restamos 50 segundos (en tu caso es 10 minutos)
const custom = datedb.clone().subtract(50, 'seconds');
// diferencia en ms
const diff = custom - moment();

setTimeout(() => {
  alert('Mensaje');
}, diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Te recomiendo en lo posible trabajar con componentes controlados para que sea React el encargado de mostrar los popups y no el DOM directamente.

Comment: Excelente, me funciono perfecto... Gracias por la ayuda...